# Data Cleaning in python

Tags: python, excel, dataset, data-cleaning

I am working on a machine learning project.The dataset involved has a feature called 'TimeStamp' in the following format, `Month12 Day9 10:20:00`.
There are over 100k of such entries. i want to change all of these in the following format `2013-07-04 00:00:00`.

How to do this in excel or python?

Comment: There is no year in the example you gave: "Month12 Day9 10:20:00". Are years all assumed to be 2013?

Comment: you can convert the input to unix timestamp and then revert back to the format that you want using the epoch timestamp

Comment: assuming the year to be 2012.

Comment: So why does `Month12 Day9 10:20:00` become `2013-07-04 00:00:00` ?

Comment: Month12 Day9 10:20:00 doesnt become 2013-07-04 00:00:00.The **format** changes from  Month12 Day9 10:20:00 to 2013-07-04 00:00:00.I mentioned the two dates as examples for the current and the required format.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like 'lakh'

Answer (score 0):

Python's `datetime` module has the pieces you need.  Specifically, you can use `strptime()` to parse a string into a `datetime` object, and `strftime()` to format a `datetime` object into a string.

Documentation:  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

You haven't said how your data is stored, but if it's in *e.g.* a CSV file, you may have good luck loading it into a pandas dataframe; pandas tends to be reasonably smart about interpreting strings as dates/times without too much help on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `re` module:

```
import re

regex = r"Month(?P<month>\d{2}) Day(?P<day>\d{1,2}) (?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"
result = r"2012-\g<month>-0\g<day> \g<time>" # Assuming the year is 2012

print(re.sub(regex, result, "Month12 Day9 10:20:00"))
```

This will print:

`2012-12-09 10:20:00`